# Elastic Search Filter performing much slower than Query

Tags: elasticsearch

As my ES index/cluster has scaled up (@ ~2 billion docs now), I have noticed more significant performance loss. So I started messing around with my queries to see if I could squeeze some perf out of them.

As I did this, I noticed that when I used a Boolean Query in my Filter, my results would take about 3.5-4 seconds to come back. But if I do the same thing in my Query it is more like 10-20ms

Here are the 2 queries:

**Using a filter**

```
POST /backup/entity/_search?routing=39cd0b95-efc3-4eee-93d1-93e6f5837d6b
{
  "query": {"bool":{"should":[],"must":[{"match_all":{}}]}},
  "filter": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "serviceId": "39cd0b95-efc3-4eee-93d1-93e6f5837d6b"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionId": "3eb5021e-2f1d-4292-9fd5-95788ebfafa0"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionType": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "entityType": [
              "4"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Using a query**

```
POST /backup/entity/_search?routing=39cd0b95-efc3-4eee-93d1-93e6f5837d6b
{
  "query": {"bool":{"should":[],"must":[
        {
          "term": {
            "serviceId": "39cd0b95-efc3-4eee-93d1-93e6f5837d6b"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionId": "3eb5021e-2f1d-4292-9fd5-95788ebfafa0"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "subscriptionType": 0
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "entityType": [
              "4"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]}}
}
```

Like I said, the second method where I don't use a Filter at all takes mere milliseconds, while the first query takes almost 4 seconds.  This seems completely backwards from what the documentation says. They say that the Filter should actually be very quick and the Query should be the one that takes longer.  So why am I seeing the exact opposite here?

Could it be something with my index mapping?  If anyone has any idea why this is happening I would love to hear suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: If you are comparing the first execution with the subsequent ones, it's not relevant. The first one might cache the filters (individual filters) while the others will use the cached filters.

Comment: If you run the **same** query (not the filter query) multiple times, do you get the same 3-4 seconds response time?

Comment: i'm comparing average response times over about 10 subsequent calls

Comment: I'm interested in each individual call, not an average. This shows if caching has any benefit or not. And the same test goes for the filter query.

Comment: I can tell caching is working because the first call on each is about double the time after I clear the cache

Comment: What ES version is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root `filter` element is actually [another name for `post_filter` element](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v1.5.2/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/search/query/QueryPhase.java#L71). Somehow, [it was supposed to be removed (the `filter`) in ES 1.1](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/8862) but it slipped through and exists in 2.x versions as well.

It is removed completely in ES 5 though.

So, your first query is not a "filter" query. It's a query whose results are used afterwards (if applicable) in aggregations, and then the `post_filter`/`filter` is applied on the results. So you basically have a two steps process in there: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/search-request-post-filter.html

More about its performance [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-optimizing-elasticsearch-searches#filter-first):

> While we have gained cacheability of the tag filter, we have potentially increased the cost of scoring significantly. Post filters are useful when you need aggregations to be unfiltered, but hits to be filtered. You should not be using post_filter (or its deprecated top-level synonym filter) if you do not have facets or aggregations.

A proper filter query is the following:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [],
          "must": [
            {
              "match_all": {}
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "term": {
                "serviceId": "39cd0b95-efc3-4eee-93d1-93e6f5837d6b"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "subscriptionId": "3eb5021e-2f1d-4292-9fd5-95788ebfafa0"
              }
            },
            {
              "term": {
                "subscriptionType": 0
              }
            },
            {
              "terms": {
                "entityType": [
                  "4"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A filter *is* faster. Your problem is that you include the `match_all` query in your filter case. This matches on *all* 2 billion of your documents. A set operation has to then be done against the filter to cull the set. Omit the `query` portion in your filter test and you'll see that the results are much faster.

Comment: I thought that as well, but when I omit the query it still has the same performance

Comment: That's really odd. Even completely omitting the query portion of the filter? A filter is a query with no scoring so it must be faster. It's also cached.